# How to resolve "create-react-app my-app" not generating my-app project and shows error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I have successfully installed creat-react-app. But when I create a project using command  `create-react-app my-app`  it shows the following errors:

*npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded*

*npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in*:
npm ERR! c:\Users\nayak\AppData\Roaming\npm-catche_logs\2019-07-10T06_27_49_749z-debug.log 
How do I resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: @s can you try `create-react-app myApp`

Answer (score 1):

Please check .npmrc file located on your user home dir Users/you/.npmrc. Backup to some other place and then remove the files, or remove the contents. You should be able to use create-react-app after that. That is something related to npm.